# WPF - Custom Button Style - Round

Tags: wpf, button, styles, wpf-controls

How I can implement a style like this in WPF:

[image]

Every part should be a button.

I do not have any ideas. Would be glad if somebody can give me some keywords to Google for. Or an example.

Comment: Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That does not help me really much ... :(